# Inner join in SQLite3

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join

I'm trying to execute an inner join in SQLite3 and it's not working. I keep getting error messages indicating that the field name in table2 is ambiguous.

Would appreciate any input as to why.

```
SELECT 
table1.id, table1.cd1, table1.cd2, table1.cd3, table1.cd4, table2.ab

FROM 
table1

INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.dx = table1.cd1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.dx = table1.cd2
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.dx = table1.cd3
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.dx = table1.cd4

GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

The field "dx" in table2 corresponds to four different fields in table1: "cd1", "cd2", "cd3", "cd4."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need table aliases:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.cd1, t1.cd2, t1.cd3, t1.cd4, ?.ab
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t21
     ON t21.dx = t1.cd1 JOIN
     table2 t22
     ON t22.dx = t1.cd2 JOIN
     table2 t23
     ON t23.dx = t1.cd3 JOIN
     table2 t24
     ON t24.dx = t1.cd4 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
```

I don't know which table `ab` is supposed to come from, so you need to fill that in.

Comment: I added aliases for the second table after each join and ran the script, with no error messages but also no results appearing in my output file.

Comment: @Harelephant . . . Then the joins don't match.  No accounting for data where things don't match.  You could try using `left join` instead.

Comment: @Harelephant Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)